# Merge sort in generic single linked list

Tags: c#, generics, linked-list, mergesort

Having some troubles with sorting, while debugging, I've found interesting thing that in method **Merge** the return data is correct, and then it join to MergeSortLL method and show that **Head** have only one node there while it must to have for ex. 5 sorted node. What could I miss here?

```
public static LinkedListNode<T> MergeSortLL<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Head) where T : IComparable<T>
{           
    if (Head == null || Head.Next == null)
        return Head;

    LinkedListNode<T> middle = GetMiddle(Head);
    LinkedListNode<T> half = middle.Next;
    middle.Next = null;

    return Merge(MergeSortLL(Head), MergeSortLL(half));
}

            public static LinkedListNode<T> Merge<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Left, LinkedListNode<T> Right) where T : IComparable<T>
            {

                var mHead = new LinkedListNode<T>(default(T));
                LinkedListNode<T> curr = mHead;

                while (Left != null && Right != null)
                {
                    if (Left.Value.CompareTo(Right.Value) <= 0)
                    {
                        curr.Next = Left;
                        Left = Left.Next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curr.Next = Right;
                        Right = Right.Next;
                    }
                    curr = curr.Next;
                }
                curr.Next = (Left == null) ? Right : Left;

                return mHead.Next;
            }

            public static LinkedListNode<T> GetMiddle<T>(LinkedListNode<T> Head) where T : IComparable<T>
            {
                if (Head == null)
                {
                    return Head;
                }

                LinkedListNode<T> slow, fast;
                slow = fast = Head;

                while (fast.Next != null && fast.Next.Next != null)
                {
                    slow = slow.Next;
                    fast = fast.Next.Next;
                }
                return slow;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could I miss here?

You are missing that the method modified the links and returns the **new** head, so it's normal the old head to show less or zero next elements.

It would be more obvious if you replace this

```
return Merge(MergeSortLL(Head), MergeSortLL(half));
```

with

```
Head = Merge(MergeSortLL(Head), MergeSortLL(half));
return Head;
```

Also don't forget to do the same in the external calls, e.g.

```
LinkedListNode<int> head = ...;
head = MergeSortLL(head);
```